# Rollover effect for only 1st image. Cancel after selecting other thumbail

Tags: javascript, html, rollover

I have a Javascript that runs a Thumbnail viewer:

```
var lastID = 0;
function SelectImg(id) {
    if (lastID > 0) {
        document.getElementById(lastID).className = "thumbNormal";
    }
    document.getElementById(id).className = "thumbSelected";
    document.getElementById(0).src = document.getElementById(id).src;
    lastID = id;
}
function LoadTrigger() {
    SelectImg(1);
}
window.onload = LoadTrigger;
```

The HTML for three images would be this

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="image">
            <img id=0 src="<?=$row['picture_noglow']?>"
            onmouseover="this.src='imgs/collection/KN/main/KNB01_Ga.jpg'"
            onmouseout="this.src='imgs/collection/KN/main/KNB01_Na.jpg'">
        </td>
        <td class="imagestack">
            <img id=1 class="thumbNormal" src="<?=$row['picture_noglow']?>" width=70 onclick="SelectImg(1)" /><p>
            <img id=2 class="thumbNormal" src="imgs/collection/defaultcase_backview_black.jpg" width=70 onclick="SelectImg(2)"><p>
            <img id=3 class="thumbNormal" src="imgs/collection/defaultcase_sideview_black.jpg" width=70 onclick="SelectImg(3)">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to apply a rollover to `id=1` only, so that when the first image is selected it will have a rollover effect.  If I selected image 2 or 3, the rollover stops.

Right now when I selected image 2 or 3, the rollover will still happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to test if the image with `id=1` is selected :

```
function mouseOverFirstImage() {
   var img1 = document.getElementById("1");

   // Test if the image is selected (if more than 1 class can
   // be applied change this test to "img1.className.match(/thumbSelected/)"
   if(img1.className === "thumbSelected")
       document.getElementById("0").src = <newImageSrc>;
}

function mouseOutFirstImage() {
   var img1 = document.getElementById("1");

   if(img1.className === "thumbSelected")
       document.getElementById("0").src = <normalImageSrc>;
}

function LoadTrigger() {
    // Add the 3 following lines to this function
    // in order to have a rollover effect
    var mainImage = document.getElementById("0");
    mainImage.onmouseover = mouseOverFirstImage;
    mainImage.onmouseout = mouseOutFirstImage;

    SelectImg(1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to Java.  I added the script you suggested but it returns with a syntax error on the line 

    var img1 = document.getElementById("1");

can you possibly paste the entire code that I'm suppose to use?

Comment: This code should replace your 3 lines `function LoadTrigger() { ... }` (and btw, it is javascript not java - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java).

Comment: hmmm not exactly what I wanted.  You can view it from here 
http://www.noctix.com/new2/KNB01.php  

I want the rollover on the main image only when it's selected.

Comment: Ok! I believed that you want the rollover on the same image that is selected... In that case, you just has to change the id of the image which is changed : in the `mouseOverFirstImage` function it becomes : `document.getElementById("0").src = <newImageSrc>;`

Comment: hmm lets try this again.  There are 3 images: A, B and C.  There's the main window that displays the thumbnail after they're selected; lets call that Z.  

By default, Z displays A; THIS IS WHERE I WANT A ROLLOVER.

Selected B or C and Z will change respectively; NO ROLLOVER.  

When A is selected again, Z displays A with ROLLOVER.  

Right now the rollover happens on the thumbnail. 

Thank you so much.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Hum... Ok, so Z is the changing image and the image over which events are triggered. If it is that, just change in the `LoadTrigger()` function the id by "0" and it should ok. I have edited my post...

Comment: Oh and sorry, you should add a test in `mouseOutFirstImage` since the image which changes is not the same as the image tested (I have looked again your updated page!)...

Comment: I had to add an IF on mouseOUT.  Otherwise mouseOUT on B and C will change the image.

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: You've been great help. Thanks